# Getting started with cls file

Tags: errors, compiling, document-classes

I need to start with CPE journal. I [downloaded their document guidelines](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1532-0634/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm), which included a `.cls`, a `.tex`, a PDF and README file.

I am using TexMaker 4.4.1 with TexLive in Mac OS X.

When I opened the TEX file provided and try to Quick Build (I did not modify anything), I have an error:

[image]

This error seems nasty for me. Could you provide some hints to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem arises because you're compiling the file `cpedoc.tex` you've downloaded with pdfLaTeX and the file contains this line

```
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
```

The `dvips` option is for when you compile with LaTeX, not with pdfLaTeX.

If you want to compile with pdfLaTeX, remove that option:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
```

Otherwise, use the chain LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf.

Comment: @TiếuThủy You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)